# Does Mathematica understand the concept of infinitesimal increment?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, differentials, variational-calculus

Commonly, in textbooks, differential of differential increment vanishes, good example is how Euler-Lagrange equations are derived using the differential (from step 2 to step 3 [here](https://martin-ueding.de/articles/euler-lagrange-equation-derivation/index.html), you can see `d[q(t) + e*eta(t)]` becomes `d[q(t)]` because `eta(t)` is infinitesimal change). And it makes sense because such small changes are considered negligible, and that is essential to define derivative rules (to see why I recommend [this video](https://youtu.be/S0_qX4VJhMQ?t=3m) at 3:00).

I would like to replicate similar behaviour in Mathematica to check correctness of certain derivations I made. Without it vanishing, my expressions will grow and not exlude negligeable terms.

I used the [DifferentialD](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferentialD.html) operator to represent differential increment, however Mathematica doesn't seem to replicate such behaviour.

I started with the following

```
DifferentialD[x + DifferentialD[y]]
```

I also tried to check if following expression be equal to zero but it wasn't the case.

```
DifferentialD[DifferentialD[y]]
```

Could someone more experienced with Mathematica (or symbolic computation in general) comment on that?

EDIT:

It appears that problem of how to handle operations on infinitesimal quantities is more deep than just simple algebra. For reference I'd like to share [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1950312/353175), it has a lot of good references and explanations.

Comment: The documentation of `DifferentialD` says "DifferentialD[x] has no built-in meaning."

Comment: There would be much less confusion in this world if people finally reached 20th century mathematics, left this "infinitesimal change" business, and learned what a (Fréchet or Gâteaux) derivative is. Actually, in the source you cite, $\eta$ is not infinitesimal at all. It is just a tangent vector and what is performed there is simply the directional derivative in that direction.

Comment: I get what you're saying, @Henrik. Thank you for quick feedback. The source says "little variation η(t), although infinitesimal", which really is confusing.

Comment: The infinitesimal part is $\epsilon$, not $\eta$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really approve of your intention but anyway. You can use

```
DifferentialD[x_ + y_] := DifferentialD[x] + DifferentialD[y]
DifferentialD[DifferentialD[x_]] := 0
```

With this, `DifferentialD[x + DifferentialD[y]]` evaluates to `DifferentialD[x]`, as required.

For completeness,

```
DifferentialD[x_^n_] := n x^(n - 1) DifferentialD[x]
DifferentialD[x_ y_] := x DifferentialD[y] + y DifferentialD[x]
```

Comment: Note: there is a built-in that does almost what OP wants, `Dt`, but one has to unprotect it and make it nilpotent, `Dt[Dt[x_]] := 0`.

Comment: Are you aware that this would make _all_ functions linear?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform since you don't approve this initiative, could you provide some examples of derivations that don't require this? For instance in the example I provided with Euler-Lagrange equations, how could that step be skipped? Because I agree with you and Henrik that this formalism is really ugly and I would love to learn a better way.

Comment: @Marek For E-L, you need [Variational Methods](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/VariationalMethods/tutorial/VariationalMethods.html).